# Assembler + C or I Can't Get Interrupts Working

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, interrupt

Help, i run the OS and it crashes! IDT Loadet normally. What i have did wrong?Its really hard! Im need to write os in protected mode!

```
    #define IT 0x000000
    #define IR 0x000800
    #define SCS 0x8
    #define IRQ_HANDLER(func) void func (void)\
     {asm(#func ": pusha \n call _" #func " \n movb $0x20, %al \n outb %al, $0x20 \n popa \n iret \n");}\
     void _ ## func(void)
        void init_interrupts() {
            int i=0;
            unsigned short *ir=IR;
            for(i=0;i<256*8;i++){
                *(ir+i)=0;
            }
            *(ir)=256*8-1;
            *(ir+2)=(IT &0xFFFF0000)>>16;
            *(ir+4)=(IT&0x0000FFFF);
            set_int_handler(0x20, timer_int_handler, 0x8E);
            //set_int_handler(0x21, print_c, 0x8E);
            asm("lidt 0(,%0,)"::"a"(IR));
            opb(0x21,0xfd);
           opb(0xa1,0xff);
            opb(0x20,0x20); opb(0xa0,0x20);
            asm("sti");
        }

        void set_int_handler(char index, void *handler, char type) {
        asm("pushf \n cli");
        char *ad=IT;
        *(ad+index*8)=(char)(handler)&0x000000FF;
        *(ad+index*8+1)=((char)(handler)&0x0000FF00)>>8;
        *(ad+index*8+2)=0x8;
        *(ad+index*8+3)=0;
        *(ad+index*8+4)=0;
        *(ad+index*8+5)=type;
        *(ad+index*8+6)=((char)(handler)&0x00FF0000)>>16;
        *(ad+index*8+7)=((char)(handler)&0xFF000000)>>24;   
        asm("popf"); 
    }
    ...
```

I dont know what to do!

Comment: You can't use inline assembly like that. The compiler doesn't promise to keep the stack in the same state as it was after your `pushf \n cli` when it executes the `popf`.

Comment: On top of the answer and comments already. I see you do `opb(0x21,0xfd); opb(0xa1,0xff);` which suggests you masked off all 16 interrupts **except** IRQ1 which is the keyboard interrupt, but then you set the interrupt handler for the timer which is IRQ0. Did you mean to do that? 0xfd = binary 11111101 which is what you set the Master PIC to which would be IRQ1. Maybe you meant 0xfe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in one way or another, most compilers allow you to [create an ISR directly](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#id1).

Second, you should be catching everything from the start unless you want the system crashing on the first unhandled or spurious interrupt (which at first look is what seems to be going on).

A proper interrupt handling subsystem would make the code much cleaner and portable, allowing you to probe IRQs for dumb buses (like ISA) and route shared IRQs cleanly.

Most emulators support the GDB protocol, and allow you to debug this sort of faults easily. For example, you can start QEMU with `-d int` and `-no-reboot` to debug this kind of issues, once a fault happens you can inspect it from the debugger. You can find some instructions to get started in the [QEMU Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Debugging_with_QEMU). You may also want to try BOCHS, it comes with an internal debugger that is better at low level stuff and the emulation is sometimes more accurate.

Comment: Most 32-bit x86 compilers don't let you create an ISR directly because protected mode interrupt handling is generally too complicated to be handled by a generic interrupt function prologue and epilogue.

Comment: GCC and Clang do, as do Borland and Watcom IIRC (has been many years...).

Comment: Hmm... GCC didn't used to, it looks like they added it only a year ago. Borland's 32-bit C compiler doesn't support it. Looks like Watcom does though.  In any case it's not very useful in an operating system because you can't access the saved registers  and you can't switch contents on interrupt return.

Comment: GNU-style syntax: `__attibute__((interrupt))`, most other compilers `__interrupt` or similar, signature requirements vary.

Comment: @RossRidge yeah, it took some time for GCC to support x86... I remeber having seen macros, helper scripts and other trickery to produce similar (clean) results.

Comment: I prefer QEMU/GDB using both the QEMU monitor and GDB at the same time *IF* the target is anything other than 16-bit real mode. Although GDB won't properly work at the point crossing from 32-bit to 64-bit code (assuming someone wanted to write a 64-bit kernel), it is possible to work around that issue by restarting the debug session with QEMU with a different architecture.It is possible to debug 16-bit real mode code, but only if the segments you use are all zero and the code is in the first 64kb. With GDB you can at least use symbolic debugging information if you also generate ELF files.

Comment: @MichaelPetch all the debuggers I've tried are broken, a workaround is to patch QEMU to report `%eip` as `%cs * 16 + %eip` when in 16-bit mode, I've used that most of the time:  http://iodev.co.uk/0001-target-i386-gdbserver-Return-CS-IP-as-EIP-on-16-bit-.patch --- it still doesn't work in the transitions.

Comment: You can get around the transition error by setting the target architecture after it aborts then reconnect. As for real mode you can make some macros as well that make real mode debugging easier. It just isn't straight forward. Usually a bootloader is small enough that real mode debugging in BOCHS is easier. Once I hit 32/64-bit code I use QEMU almost exclusively for 32-bit and 64-bit kernel debugging. Of course it is always good to run it on a variety of emulators and real hardware.

Comment: @MichaelPetch no, the thing is it will report wrongly when transitioning, after you set the flag but before the jump, and can only be fixed in the debugger side.

Comment: Without even patching QEMU you can do this. After you make the jump (let us say from 32-bit mode to 64-bit mode) you'll get a string of numbers and disconnected. Just because the remote debug session was terminated doesn't mean it can't be restarted. What I usually do after the transition aborts is issue these commands:  `disconnect` `set architecture i386:x86-64:intel` and then `target remote localhost:1234` to reconnect. You can do a similar thing transitioning from 16-bit mode to 32-bit mode if that aborts.

Comment: @MichaelPetch the problem isn't getting disconnected, but that you can't debug the transitions because of the inconsistent interpretation of the state of the processor, which is a rather important flaw.